# Glue (pyspark) how to specify jdbc SaveMode to ingore

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, save, aws-glue, mode

I would like to write a Glue DynamicFrame to a MySQL databse (non RDS, but a simple ec2 mysql instance)

This is how I'm currently doing:

```
datasink = glueContext.write_from_options(test, 'mysql', {"url": jdbcUrl, "user": userName, "password": dbPassword, "dbtable": myTable }, {}, {}, "datasink")
```

How can I specify the saveMode? Do I need to transform the DynamicFrame to a simple DataFrame and use the .write.jdbc ?